# Show value in new activity?

Tags: android

Can someone tell me why i don't get showed number **2** in second Activity

**My MainActivity:**

```
Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);


            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putInt("key", 2);

            ii.putExtras(b);

            startActivity(ii);

            finish();
        }
    });
```

***Second Activity:***

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    int value = b.getInt("key", 0);

    text.setText(value);
```

Pleas tell me what is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the parameters with the intent, not with a bundle

```
Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);

bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        ii.putExtra("key", 2); //<-- this
        startActivity(ii);

        finish();
    }
});
```

in the second activity you get the key :

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    int value =getIntent().getIntExtra("key", 0);
    text.setText(value);
```

Comment: oh yea.. But I get error at ii.putInt <--  "The method putInt(String, int) is undefined for the type Intent"

Comment: yea sorry, it is "putExtra"